# adding subviews in UINavigationBar with buttons doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have a UINavigationController subclass and in the viewDidLoad I had the following code:

```
self.containerView_ = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frameHeight)];
    [self.containerView_ setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [self.containerView_ setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];

    self.profileButton_ = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
    [self.profileButton_ addTarget:self action:@selector(showProfileView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.profileButton_ setCenterY:self.navigationController.navigationBar.frameHeight/2];
    [self.profileButton_ setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.socialButton_ = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.profileButton_.frameRight + 10, 0, 30, 30)];
    [self.socialButton_ addTarget:self action:@selector(showSocialView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.socialButton_ setCenterY:self.profileButton_.centerY];
    [self.socialButton_ setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"social_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    self.notesButton_ = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.socialButton_.frameRight + 10, 0, 30, 30)];
    [self.notesButton_ addTarget:self action:@selector(showNotesView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.notesButton_ setCenterY:self.profileButton_.centerY];
    [self.notesButton_ setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notes_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    [self.containerView_ addSubview:self.profileButton_];
    [self.containerView_ addSubview:self.notesButton_];
    [self.containerView_ addSubview:self.socialButton_];

    [self.navigationBar addSubview:self.containerView_];
```

I can see the UIButton but the container background is not even yellow color. When I press the button, the action of the UIButton is not called. Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are subclassing UINavigationController?

To quote Apple: "This class is not intended for subclassing."

The usual way to tweak the UINavController is to access the navBar from the perspecitve of a contained UIViewController. You would put the target/action methods in the UIViewController.